# How to specify the file path in which to download using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve ("http://bogoroditsa.tk/Grant's%20Libraries/", "ExtraFunctionality.py")
```

How do I specify, using the command above, the file path in which to download the file?
Currently, the code above just downloads the file in the same path as the program is being run in. I would like to specify this download path, how do I do so?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path as the second argument?..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of just `"ExtraFunctionality.py"` you can also provide a full path:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve ("http://bogoroditsa.tk/Grant's%20Libraries/",
                                             "/home/foo/ExtraFunctionality.py")
```

Answer (score 4):

The second argument is the local filename:

```
 urllib.urlretrieve ("http://bogoroditsa.tk/Grant's%20Libraries/ExtraFunctionality.py", theLocalFilename)
```

For details, see the [documentation for urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html), under urlretrieve:

> The second argument, if present, specifies the file location to copy to (if absent, the location will be a tempfile with a generated name).